# clojure-mode put-clojure-indent with prefix or regular expression?

Tags: emacs, clojure

In emacs clojure-mode, is there a way to `define-clojure-indent` with a prefix or regular expression, rather than a full symbol?

I am working on a project with a variety of macros named with a `foreach-` prefix.  I would like `(foreach-foo ...)` to be indented the same way as `(with-foo ...)`.

Answer (score 1):

As far as I can see `clojure-mode` doesn't provide such possibility.  Indentation for `with-foo` like forms [is hardcoded](https://github.com/clojure-emacs/clojure-mode/blob/464c9de6734cb4b426137674041d695c2a7c7ef9/clojure-mode.el#L1247) in sources, so you may modify couple of lines to get desired behavior. Otherwise, you'll need to explicitly set indentation for all the symbols.